# you probably read this wrong!

Tags: cipher, computer-puzzle

Read this carefully:

```
‮114 116 108 111

https://repl.it/010010010100‮11000110110001011000
```

What's my message?

Hint:

> you probAbLy read This wrong!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hidden in the text is a

> [Right-to-left Override](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202e/index.htm), which makes some of the text appear backwards. (You can see this by highlighting it.) There's one in both the first and the second lines; the first line decodes to `rtlo` as decimal ASCII, which gives confirmation.

Taking the link,

> removing the binary, and decoding leads you to https://repl.it/ILlX.

Take that number and

> translate it to hexadecimal. (Pad with a 0 at the beginning.) You get a set of Unicode codepoints that translate to **`Σimply βeautiful art`**, the answer.

Comment: Hm, either I missed something, or your end message is missing a few letters, as per my username.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: I figured it would be something like that, but wasn't sure if I missed anything. I assume it's just "Σimply βeautiful αrt", or something to that effect?

Comment: Yes, that should be the end message